# Loading json in SwiftUI with dynamic struct

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to load json data into SwiftUI, to be parsed as a List of data.
All the examples I've seen so far, require a struct for the data's format predefined.
e.g.
Data:

```
[{
   "column1": "abc"
}]
```

Struct:

```
struct Item: Hashable, Codable{
    var column1: String
}
```

I tried loading a json with less columns than the struct and unfortunately it will cause errors.
Is it possible to support a dynamic json whereby the number of keys ("column1", "column2" etc.) in the json is not fixed? For example in Javascript, it is very possible to just JSON.parse any valid string into an array.

Thanks in advance!

Edit to provide my JSON data and code:

```
[
    {
        "column0": "value0",
        "column1": "value1",
        "column2": "value2",
        "column3": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "column0": "valueA",
        "column1": "valueB",
        "column2": "valueC",
        "column3": "No"
    },
]
```

I can have another JSON result which might be:

```
[
    {
        "column0": "value0",
        "column1": "value1",
    },
    {
        "column0": "valueA",
        "column1": "valueB",
    },
]
```

The loading JSON code (taken from Apple's SwiftUI Tutorial here https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation):

```
let itemData:[Item] = load(_filename: "testData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_filename: String)-> T{
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: _filename, withExtension: nil)
        else{
            fatalError()
    }
    
    do{
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    }
    catch{
        fatalError()
    }
    
    do{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that it would be something in this step I could adjust, but I might be wrong.

Comment: SwiftUI has nothing to JSON parsing!

Comment: Please also share your code and input JSON.

Comment: Are you referring to [this experiment](https://twitter.com/navdeep_ua/status/1284891061920206850?s=21)?

Comment: Not fully. That JSON remains the same structure throughout. Only variable number of entries in the array which is a value of one of the keys. I might have different number of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above for giving me a clue, I think I've got it working.
In case it might be useful for others, I'm posting what I did here.

data.json as above, wrapped in a "body".

However the struct is like this:

```
struct ResponseObject: Hashable, Codable{ 
    var body: [Dictionary<String, String>]
}
```

As for the view:

```
VStack{
    ForEach(responseData.body[0].sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
        Text(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Try a optional array string. But make sure your array has a attribute. This case set it up to body, can be anything.

```
{ body: [
    {
        "column0": "value0",
        "column1": "value1",
        "column2": "value2",
        "column3": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "column0": "valueA",
        "column1": "valueB",
        "column2": "valueC",
        "column3": "No"
    },
]
}
```

```
struct Item: Hashable, Codable{
    var body: [String: [String]]?
}
```

In case you cant rename it. Just create another struct to hold it inside as such.

```
struct Composer: Codable {
 var body: String?
}
```

Now you build your response like this.

```
let rsp = Composer(body: myRespo)
```

now encode JSON rsp because it matches your new struct.